# Why do we not have a (soft-question) tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, tags

Some sites on the Stack Exchange network have the tag (soft-question), used on a question that "does not admit a definitive answer".  Why don't other sites, e.g., Stack Overflow, have this tag?  I find it to be quite useful.

Comment: Because we're really strict on those questions, and close them as primarily opinion-based instead. If they can survive that, they don't need a tag.

Answer (score 16):

We used to. It was called "subjective". [It died a brutal death after two years of bitter arguments.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Here's the kicker: if you're asking a question that you *know* you don't want an answer to, you shouldn't be asking it at all. This isn't the place to invite folks to share their stories or speculate on things they have no possible way of knowing.

If you actually have a real problem to solve, then **just state the problem and ask for help solving it** - if it turns out there *isn't* a definitive answer, then... well, it sucks to be you, but I expect you'll be happier *knowing that* than listening to dozens of folks just as clueless as yourself pontificating on it anyway.

Either way, we don't need [a scarlet letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scarlet_Letter) for questions that are a bit fuzzy. Either someone can provide a reasonably justified answer, or we get rid of the question entirely. [There's no place for unanswerable questions on a Q&A site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)...

Comment: The soft-question tag still exists on some Stack Exchange sites, [including math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question). If that's the case, then should we delete this tag (and all similar tags) from all sites on the Stack Exchange Network?

Comment: You can think of them as somewhat vestigial there; they exist, they're used, but questions in them don't get a pass when it comes to having to ask actual questions. IOW, it's still a lousy tag, but remains because trying to remove it has kicked up more drama than leaving it. This may change at some point - it's really up to the folks who make up those sites.

Comment: Why did you suddenly decide to re-open and edit the question?

Comment: I didn't edit the question. Someone decided to create busywork for me by closing it, and I reopened because I have enough busywork; the edits were made by someone else, and seem helpful enough.